# Can the ctor be marked noexcept based on allocator type?

Tags: c++, allocator, noexcept, c++pmr

How should I make sure that a constructor is `noexcept` if the allocator does not throw?

Here is an MRE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>


template < std::unsigned_integral T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T> >
class Foo
{
    std::vector<T, Allocator> vec;

public:
    Foo( const size_t size, const T value,
         const Allocator& alloc = Allocator { } ) noexcept( noexcept( Allocator { } ) )
    : vec { size, value, alloc }
    {
    }
};

int main( )
{
    Foo<unsigned> my_foo { 10, 505 };

    auto buffer { std::array<std::byte, 50> { } };
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource rsrc { buffer.data( ), buffer.size( ) };

    Foo< unsigned, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<unsigned> > my_foo_pmr { 10, 505, &rsrc };


    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << noexcept( std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<unsigned> { } ) << '\n' // true
              << noexcept( std::allocator<unsigned> { } ) << '\n'                  // true
              << std::noboolalpha;
}
```

First of all, I wonder why does `noexcept( std::allocator<unsigned> { } )` return **true**? Is `std::allocator<unsigned>` exception safe? Like a vector with this allocator never throws? And what about the **pmr** allocator that has a stack-based buffer? Can it throw?

Secondly, what is the proper way of ensuring that the above class's ctor is marked `noexcept` if it actually never throws?

Comment: please one question per question. Why `true` ? Because the constructor is `noexcept`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocator

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Ok, but isn't a dynamic allocation potentially throwing? I don't quite understand this.

Comment: You aren't testing `Allocator::allocate`, only the c'tor. And initializing the allocator is non-throwing.

Comment: `std::allocator<unsigned> { }` constructs a `std::allocator<unsigned>`. Do you perhaps want to check if the allocators methods throw? Its not quite clear in your quesiton what you mean with " if the allocator does not throw"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number What I mean is that will the ctor of Foo throw if `std::allocator<unsigned> { }` is passed to the `vec`'s ctor? I want to make sure not to mark the `Foo` ctor `noexcept` if it is potentially throwing.

Comment: you want to check if constructing the allocator throws? I think thats what you are doing

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Probably not just the allocator itself but also the construction of member variable `vec`. If the ctor of `vec` throws then `Foo`'s ctor should not be marked `noexcept`, right? How do I make sure that things go well?

Comment: @BoP Is that true even for the pmr vector? Do you mean that `Foo`'s ctor can never be marked as noexcept? And that it is always potentially throwing?

Comment: the vector constructor that takes count, element and allocator is not `noexcept`. I dont understand why you focus on the allocator only, perhaps you confused it with the vectors default constructor which is indeed `noexcept( noexcept(Allocator())` but thats not that relevant when you call a different constuctor https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: @digito_evo - The vector constructor taking those 3 parameters is not noexcept, so it can formally throw. Specifically for out-of-memory.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yeah I guess I get it now. I also tested the `allocate` member function like `noexcept( std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<unsigned> { }.allocate( 1000 ) )` and it returns **false**. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I was just trying to understand what you mean ;). But yes, this `noexcept( noexcept( Allocator())` thingy is only interesting when you construct an empty vector. Once you add elements neither the vector nor the allocator can ensure that you'll have enough memory or no other exceptions occur

Comment: actually I am not really into custom allocators, but even if the allocator would allocate a large chunk up front in its constructor, then the constructor might throw, and still later you can run out of space. So I don't know if there can be an allocator that really never throws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, I wonder why does `noexcept( std::allocator<unsigned> { } )` return `true`?

Because constructing a `std::allocator<unsigned>` does not throw.

> Secondly, what is the proper way of ensuring that the above class's ctor is marked noexcept if it actually never throws?

The proper way is to not mark it as `noexcept` because it may throw. The vector constructor you are calling is not `noexcept`. Only `std::vectors` default constructor is `noexcept( noexcept(Allocator())`, but you are calling a different constructor. With a `pmr` allocator I suppose nothing is different, because when `size` is too big then being able to construct the allocator without exceptions does not help to avoid running out of memory once you allocate too many elements.

Comment: I did not know the distinction between default constructing an allocator and its `allocate` non-static member function. Apparently, I had to check the exception safeness of that member function instead of the ctor of allocator type.

Comment: @digito_evo hm... why do you focus on the allocator? You are calling the constructor of `std::vector` : `vec { size, value, alloc }` and this is never `noexcept`

Comment: Yes, that's valid reasoning. I should have noticed it when I checked the docs of vector's ctor a few hours ago. But I also wanted to know why a non-empty vector can never be exception-safe even if it uses a pmr allocator.